# Visual Studio 2015 Installation Problems

Tags: visual-studio

I am having major problems with installing Visual Studio 2015 that I have been dealing with since its release on Monday. I uninstalled Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate and installed Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise and this happened:

[image: Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Installation Error]

The installation has not only partially failed, but Visual Studio is not even completely installed, and `devenv.exe` is missing from the folder. Is there a way that I can wipe everything related to Visual Studio from my machine, including plugins, extensions, etc. and start fresh? I'm trying to run an installation repair at the moment, but I don't believe it is going to get me anything.

I'm extremely frustrated to the point of anger at the moment, so please try to be patient with me.

**UPDATE: Visual Studio is now working, but I still have one problem with the Windows Phone SDK not installing. Any ideas for a fix?**

[image: Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Installation Error]

Here is what the log file has to reveal on the failed Windows Phone 8.1 SDK installation.

```
[0120:18C0][2015-07-23T15:01:25]i000: MUX:  P5 - Windows Phone 8.1 SDK
[0120:18C0][2015-07-23T15:01:25]i000: MUX:  P6 - Install
[0120:18C0][2015-07-23T15:01:25]i000: MUX:  P7 - 0x80070643
[0120:18C0][2015-07-23T15:01:25]i000: MUX:  P8 - There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. 
[0120:18C0][2015-07-23T15:01:25]i000: MUX:  P9 -
```

Comment: I gave up uninstalling anything long time ago. Never seems to go down well.  Nowdays when I upgrade major software versions, I wipe the hard drive and install OS + Updates + Software from scratch. I would recommend you do the same when moving up from VS2013 to VS2015. In the end it's far easier to do that than deal with the mess you're in, and you end up with a clean robust installation to enjoy until the next major version bump.

Comment: To add weight to my previous comment, check this out: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3487794-create-a-remove-all-remnants-of-visual-studio-fro. Nothing has changed since then and MS have not created a tool that would properly uninstall the myriad components VS installs on the system.

Comment: @misha256 I saw the link you posted in your second comment when looking for a solution on Google. I was able to install Visual Studio 2015 by reverting back to Windows 8.1 with only two remaining problems: the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK failed to install and no entries for Visual Studio have been made in `Programs and Features`. Any idea on how to fix either of these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the Windows 10 update caused more problems with my computer, I ended up reimaging my machine and starting fresh. When the time came for me to install Visual Studio 2015, everything worked perfectly. I never found out what the problem actually was, and I am aware that this is not very helpful for those who do not want to reimage the machine.